# Matlab table indexing fails after error

Tags: matlab

I'm finding that table indexing is not working when an error is thrown, which makes debugging...difficult.  Anyone else find the same behaviour, and/or can suggest an efficient way to make the problem go away?

To replicate the behaviour, I create two simple m-files:

```
% script.m
%---------
dbstop if error
func


% func.m
%-------
function func
y=table((1:4)','RowNames',{'a','b','c d','ef'})
y('zz',:) % Throws error to enter debugger
end % function func
```

I then enter the following commands

```
script
dbup % Enter base workspace to create new variable y
y=table((1:4)','RowNames',{'a','b','c d','ef'})
y(1,1) % Returns whole table, not data within table
```

The output is as follows:

```
>> script
y = 
           Var1
           ____
    a      1   
    b      2   
    c d    3   
    ef     4   
Error using func (line 3)
Unrecognized row name 'zz'.
Error in script (line 1)
func 
65      throwAsCaller(ME)

K>> dbup % Enter base workspace to create new variable y
In workspace belonging to func (line 3)

K>> y=table((1:4)','RowNames',{'a','b','c d','ef'})
y = 
           Var1
           ____
    a      1   
    b      2   
    c d    3   
    ef     4   

K>> y(1,1) % Returns whole table, not data within table
ans = 
           Var1
           ____
    a      1   
    b      2   
    c d    3   
    ef     4
```

As can be seen, y(1,1) yields the whole table rather than the entry in row 1, column 1.

NOTE: This problematic behaviour is not generally seen in debugger mode, but only after an error (which is when I want to use the debugger!).  To see the expected nonproblematic behaviour,  I set a breakpoint in func.m at the statement:

```
y('zz',:)
```

which for me is line 3, since I don't have any of the opening comment lines:

```
dbquit
clear all
clear classes
dbstop in func at 3
```

I then ran the following statements to get the the breakpoint and index into tables:

```
script % Stops in func.m at statement y('zz',:)
y(1,1) % Now yields entry at row 1, column 1
dbup % See if new table in base workspace also behaves well
y=table((1:4)','RowNames',{'a','b','c d','ef'}) % New table
y(1,1) % Returns entry at row 1, column 1, as expected
```

I am using Matlab version 2015a.

P.S. The original problem was encountered using row name indexing, but I've troubleshot the issue to the above simpler example.

Comment: cannot reproduce this behavior on MATLAB R2015a, running on my Mac. Could you confirm that you set the breakpoint on the line "y('zz',:) % Throws error to enter debugger" in func.m?

Comment: @akamath: Thanks for pointing that out. I sussed out the conditions under which the weird behaviour is seen -- only when an error is thrown.  I revised the question accordingly.  Still hoping for a way to get rid of the behaviour....

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @Matthias W.: This is really odd.  I'm wondering if the difference between me & you (& akamath) is that I issued "dbstop if error".  I just added this to script.m in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation from TMW:

In your example, the error is thrown within the "subsref" method of the Table class. The "subsref" method is what defines the subscripted reference, or indexing, behaviors of objects in MATLAB. MATLAB allows users to overload the "subsref" method to define custom indexing behaviors for custom classes and objects.

In terms of "subsref" behavior for overloaded versions, the following information is mentioned in documentation (the links are included below):

"MATLAB does not call class-defined 'subsref' or 'subsasgn' methods within the overloaded methods. Within class methods, MATLAB always calls the built-in 'subsref' and 'subsasgn' functions."

"Calling the built-in enables you to use the default indexing behavior when defining a specialized indexing."

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/indexed-reference-and-assignment.html#br09nsm

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsref.html#moreabout

Now, in reference to your example, since the error is thrown within the "subsref" method of the Table class, this establishes the setting for the following steps in your debugging process. When using the "dbup" command to shift the workspace to the workspace of the caller function, it allows you to inspect the variables in the function's workspace, to see what was passed into the function that threw the error, and to determine what might have led to this issue.

However, in your example, we are still technically stuck in the catch-portion of the table "subsref" method, as a result of the error thrown from erroneous indexing. As mentioned above, by default, MATLAB does not call class-defined "subsref" methods from WITHIN an overloaded "subsref" method. We are still technically inside the table's overloaded method, so any indexing takes on the built-in behavior during the debugging. This is why the entire table is returned; this is the built-in behavior. The correct indexing intended for tables is not feasible in this debugging process.

As an additional note, part of the motivation behind this behavior is to avoid falling into an infinite loop by calling the "subsref" method, through indexing, while already inside that method. Instead of calling itself, it will call the built-in method.